# Question about domain of differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am reading *Multivariable Mathematics* by Ted Shifrin, and I'm a bit unclear about the domain of differential forms.

For example, in the form $f(x) dx$, suppose the domain of $dx$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Must the domain of $f(x)$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? If so, must the input for $f$ and for $dx$ be the same? (i.e., is it correct to write $f(x) dx(x)$, or should we rather write $f(x) dx(v))$?

Comment: the domain of a differential form is the tangent space of the manifold where this differential form is defined. If the manifold is $\mathbb{R}^n$ then it domain is $T\mathbb{R}^n$, then for $(p,v)\in T\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $dx$ is the map $(p,v)\mapsto dx_p(v)$ where $dx_p$ is a linear functional in $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: in my previous comment I assumed that $dx$ is a 1-form. If we have $f(x)dx$ then the map will be $(p,v)\mapsto f(p)dx_p(v)$. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form)

Comment: The domain of a differential 1-form is a subset of the **tangent bundle**. Did you already learn what it is?